# Virtualisation on Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization

Im looking to virtualize my linux server on Server 08. I remember reading somewhere that Server 08 has built in visualization capabilites, is this ture? and how do i use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's called 'Hyper-V' and here's a link ([Clicky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V)) to the wikipedia article on it. It works fine right now but is still a number of years behind VMWare, that will change though and plenty of people are using it in production or semi-production environments.